# pass form values formData React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to submit form using below code

```
    let formData = new FormData();    

formData.append('name', 'ABC');   
formData.append('age', 20);

const config = {     
    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
}

axios.post(url, formData, config)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I have 15 fields in my form. I want to know one thing. do i need to append all fields to submit my form.

```
    formData.append('name', 'ABC');   
    formData.append('age', 20);
  // 13 appends here like above 2 fields??
```

do i need append all other 13 fields here ? or have any alternative and short code way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store your form data into an array and then copy this array like this :

```
fromData.append(...array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `refs()` and `state` to build the form data object with named `attributes`. Please note `name` attribute plays a big part for the elements. Make sure you name them exactly what you want to fetch/use.

PS: *You also need to make sure the api receiving handles the data format correctly.  I havent touched this part as OP was about formData*

Small eg:

```
const UserForm = props => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(props.user)
  const form = useRef(null)

  const submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = new FormData(form.current)
    fetch('/api', { method: 'POST', body: data })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(/*Do something*/)
  }

  return (
    <form ref={form} onSubmit={submit}>
      <input type="text" name="user[name]" defaultValue={user.name} />
      <input type="email" name="user[email]" defaultValue={user.email} />
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: i am using formik library to submit my form. is this ok for it?